# JPA Criteria Query: How to select default value for multiSelect

Tags: java, jpa, criteria

I have a class with 11 field for multiSelect query.

My problem is, currently, I have data for 10 field. One of them is `null` and will be use in the future.

```
query.multiselect(
    selection1,
    selection2,
    ...
    selection10
)
```

So, I create new constructor with 10 field but it make code is smell because too many parameter. I think it better if my multiselect look like:

```
query.multiselect(
    selection1,
    selection2,
    ...
    selection10,
    selection11 // this should return default null value
)
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[CriteriaQuery.multiselect](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaQuery.html#multiselect-javax.persistence.criteria.Selection...-) takes a list of [Selection](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/persistence/criteria/Selection.html) objects. The `Selection` interface is extended by [Expression](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/persistence/criteria/Expression.html), and you can use [CriteriaBuilder.literal](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaBuilder.html#literal-T-) to create a constant expression. Or [CriteriaBuilder.nullLiteral](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaBuilder.html#nullLiteral-java.lang.Class-) for the case you want a constant `null`. So I would try:

```java
query.multiselect(
    selection1,
    selection2,
    ...
    selection10,
    criteriaBuilder.nullLiteral(String.class) // use the class of the value that
                                              // will be selected in the future
)
```